# How does Java's date work?

Tags: java, date

Hi I have a following code below:

```
public Date convertFromGMTToLocal(Date date) {
     return new Date(date.getTimezoneOffset() + newOffset*60*1000);  
}

public Date convertFromLocalToGMT(Date date) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);
}
```

convertFromLocalToGMT is supposed to strip off timezone information and convertFromGMTToLocal is supposed to put the timezone information back. I understand java.util.Date is representing the time in epoch and always in GMT however when displaying the date it is defaulted to JVM's default timezone.

Explanation I got was that if your timezone is CST and it is 10:00AM CST you are changing timezone to GMT with convertFromLocalToGMT so you're essentially adding the offset to get GMT so you get 4:00AM CST (offset is -6) and using convertFromGMTToLocal will **convert this Date object back to 10:00AM regardless of your timezones** (the most confusing part how?). How does above work? I am confused...

Thanks.

Comment: How does Java's date work?
Badly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should pretty much *never* add an offset to a `Date` to create another `Date` - you'd *only* ever do that if you received broken data to start with.

You should **not** use this code. It is bad code which tries to treat `java.util.Date` in a way it was not designed for. If you want to represent a date in a particular time zone, either use `Calendar` (urgh) or the *far* better [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) API.

In particular, the code you've got will *not* work around time zone transitions - because the offset at `date.getTimeZoneOffset()` still considers `date` to be UTC (because that's what it's defined as) even you're *treating* it as a local date/time.

Ignore the value that's displayed by `Date.toString()` - avoid using that method. *Either* display using `SimpleDateFormat` with appropriate settings for the time zone you're interested in, or (better, again) use Joda's `DateTimeFormat` class.

Comment: The problem we had was we wanted to get rid of notion of "timezone" form the date. So if we get 10:00AM today no matter which timezone you're at we should display 10:00AM. In order to achieve this above transition was necessary, treating them all in GMT will allow us to display this Date as 10:00AM regardless of the timezone.

Comment: @Mayumi: In that case you should use `LocalDateTime` or `LocalTime` from Joda. If you *must* use `Date`/`Calendar`, then simply use UTC for *all* operations, and remember that you've done so. But you don't need to *convert* from a local time zone to do that - simply parse it in UTC to start with. (I'm assuming you received this value in text form somehow. If you could be clearer on that point, it would really help.)

Comment: +1 - The OP's code should be redesigned / rewritten to use a better date representation class.

Comment: +1 I really think Joda Time should just be packaged with the next major version of java

Comment: "simply use UTC for all operations" isn't Date already in UTC? What I am most confused about is the behavior of java.util.Date. When you (date.getTime() - 300 (CST)*60*1000) what is the behavior? Date does come with timezone offset information which is defaulted to machine time, for example if you save (new Date()) into datastore and retrieve it in machine with different timezone would this offset update?

Comment: @Mayumi: Yes, `Date` is always in UTC, but if you *parse* some text that doesn't specify a time zone, you have to give information about which time zone to consider it as part of. Date itself does *not* include any time zone offset information - it's used when *displaying* the information, but it's not part of the information within the `Date` itself. If you use `date.getTime() - 300*60*1000` that gets you something I call `LocalInstant` in Noda Time, but which doesn't really have a fixed terminology in Java. What do you mean by "what is the behaviour"? (Continued.)

Comment: Fundamentally a `Date` with a value of `date.getTime() - 300*60*1000` represents the *UTC instant* 5 hours before the original one. That's *not* the same thing as representing a local time. Again, just don't do it - it's using `Date` in a way which it was not intended.

Comment: @Jon: We are using GWT which doesn't work with Joda or Calendar.
This is for a scheduling application. When someone books an appointment for 10:00AM, we want it to display as 10:00AM no matter where the user (or server) is. It will be implied that the time is in the vendor's time zone.

By the same token, we don't want the vendor to create a bunch of appointments, then realize that they set the timezone wrong, correct the mistake, and have all the appointments shift. (This is different behaviour from Google Calendar, for example, where the appointments all shift if you change the time zone.)

Comment: This is why we don't store in the vendor's timezone either but instead, convert all appointments to a common timezone (in this case, GMT).

Comment: @Mayumi: Okay, that sounds like the right approach - but how do you receive the information to start with? Basically, if you receive it as text in the form "10:00AM" then you should be parsing that *in UTC*. It's not really clear how your data is flowing at the moment or where conversions are taking place.

Comment: @Mayumi: Btw, it looks like there are various ports of Joda Time for GWT. I don't know how complete or valid any of them are.

Answer (score 4):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

You can solve it using the following functions in `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API :

1. **[`LocalDateTime#atZone(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-)**
2. **[`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-)**

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

/*
 * Change the JVM's ZoneId, ZoneId.systemDefault() to the required ZoneId e.g. ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC");
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2021, 5, 10), LocalTime.of(15, 20), zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdt + " is " + convertFromZdtToLdt(zdt) + " at " + ZoneId.systemDefault().getId());

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2021, 5, 10), LocalTime.of(15, 20));
        System.out
                .println(ldt + " at " + ZoneId.systemDefault().getId() + " is " + convertFromLdtZdtToZdt(ldt, zoneId));
    }

    public static LocalDateTime convertFromZdtToLdt(ZonedDateTime zdt) {
        return zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    }

    public static ZonedDateTime convertFromLdtZdtToZdt(LocalDateTime ldt, ZoneId targetZoneId) {
        return ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).withZoneSameInstant(targetZoneId);
    }
}
```

**Output on my system in Europe/London timezone:**

```
2021-05-10T15:20Z[Etc/UTC] is 2021-05-10T16:20 at Europe/London
2021-05-10T15:20 at Europe/London is 2021-05-10T14:20Z[Etc/UTC]
```

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2yslHu)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: The ONLINE DEMO gives the same Date-Time for the source and target in the output because the timezone of Ideone server is set as UTC (or GMT) .

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the Date object doesn't care about timezone. It stores an instant in time. The timezone is only meaningful when you want to display a date. Use a `DateFormat` with the specific timezone you want to use to display a date (using [setTimeZone](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29))